# Matlab: how to make [1 3 5] become [1 nan 3 nan 5]

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, nan

If there is an array called `numbers` shown below. How can I transform this array so that `numbers` becomes `realNumbers` as shown below where any number from `1:10` that does not exist in `numbers` is filled with a `nan`. `realNumbers` is what I want as the result and doesn't exist before the computation and only `numbers` exists. This is in Matlab code.

```
numbers = [1 3 5 6 10];
realNumbers = [1 nan 3 nan 5 6 nan nan nan 10];
```

Comment: This is implied from your example to an extent, but, when you say `real`, you mean `real`, or specifically `integers`? Because the answers you're getting below are specific to `integers`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way, using the very versatile [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) function:

```
numbers = [1 3 5 6 10];
realNumbers = accumarray(numbers(:), numbers(:), [], @(x)x(1), NaN).';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
realNumbers = nan(1,10);
realNumbers(numbers) = numbers
```

Comment: How could this be done without preallocating the nan array? Also, `realNumbers` is what I want as the result and doesn't exist before the computation. Only `numbers` exists.

Comment: what about nan(min(numbers),max(numbers)). Is your vector allways sorted? Is it allways with unique numbers? Does it allways start with 1?

Comment: The vector `numbers` is always sorted with unique numbers but can start with any number (does not necessarily always start with 1).

Comment: does numbers ever have a `0` in it? otherwise you could do this:
`realnumbers(numbers)=numbers;
realnumbers(realnumbers==0)=NaN;`  
but actually shai's solution looks good to me. why do you not want to preallocate the `NaN`-array? Edit: what do you mean by "realnumbers doesn't exist before the computation"? how does that matter?

Answer (score 3):

You already have answers for when the numbers are *integers*. Your question, however, specifically asks for *real* numbers in general, so I will give a more general solution.

```
>> Numbers = [0.5, 2, 3.5]
Numbers =
   0.5  2.0  3.5
>> RealNumbers = [0:0.5:5]
RealNumbers =
   0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0
>> Members = ismember (RealNumbers, Numbers)
Members =
   0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
>> RealNumbers(~Members) = nan
RealNumbers =
   NaN  0.5  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  3.5  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: PS: `ismember` also has the advantage that the ordering in `RealNumbers` / `Numbers` does not matter.